# Buffering in Node

Tags: node.js

I'm learning basic node before I delve in to frameworks such as connect and express. I've come across the subject of buffers. When do I need to use buffers in node and how do I know how big to make the buffer?

If I have a string of text being sent in a POST request do I need to buffer this?

```
var server = http.createServer(function(req,res) {
    var body = '';
    req.setEncoding('utf8');
    req.on('data', function(chunk) { body += chunk});
    req.on('end', function() { //... });
});
```

I know connect provides limit() functionality but I'm not sure if this defers to buffer in the background. With that aside I'm specifically interested to know if, in vanilla node, I need to use buffers for data such as JSON and strings or should I just use a buffer when I have data that could potentially be large like a file upload?

Comment: I'm specifically interested in vanillia node

Comment: Yeah, I noticed. Well, yes you'll need to do this. As for file upload, or any raw data like Text, Json, Xml you'll have to buffer it just like what you've shown.

Comment: But my code doesn't show any buffer? It's just receiving the chunked data and appending to the body var. I think I need to use the buffer class? http://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html

Comment: `chunk` is already a buffer. but then you set the encoding to utf8 so now the buffer is turned into a string.

Comment: But I need utf8 encoding as the text is a string. Otherwise I'm going to be concatenating binary data with body+= chunk? Hence the need for the buffer?

Comment: you can build the utf8 data then wrap it as a buffer again. like `var binary = new Buffer(body)`;

Comment: So concatenate the chunked data as strings and then buffer afterwards?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are asking for but you have 2 options here.
You either retrieve all the data as string then wrap it as a buffer or concat the buffer immediately.

### new Buffer

```
var server = http.createServer(function(req,res) {
    var body = '';
    req.setEncoding('utf8');
    req.on('data', function(chunk) { body += chunk});
    req.on('end', function() {
      var myBuffer = new Buffer(body); // this is now a buffer of the received chunks
    });
});
```

### Buffer.concat

```
var server = http.createServer(function(req,res) {
    var bufs = [];
    req.on('data', function(chunk) { bufs.push(chunk); });
    req.on('end', function() {
      var myBuffer = Buffer.concat(bufs); // this is now a buffer of the received chunks
    });
});
```

### Note

> Pure JavaScript is Unicode friendly but not nice to binary data. When
>   dealing with TCP streams or the file system, it's necessary to handle
>   octet streams. Node has several strategies for manipulating, creating,
>   and consuming octet streams.
>
> Raw data is stored in instances of the Buffer class. A Buffer is
>   similar to an array of integers but corresponds to a raw memory
>   allocation outside the V8 heap. A Buffer cannot be resized.
>
> The Buffer class is a global, making it very rare that one would need
>   to ever require('buffer').

- [source](http://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html)

Comment: Ok cool. I see. And then how do you get the utf8 data back from the buffer? Is it myBuffer.toString() ?

Comment: That is right. `toString()` should do the trick. Though if you really want the utf8 data then just use the `wrap` option. Then just `new Buffer(string)` when you really need the binary.